# Car vibration evaluated by Fast Fourier Transform in Octave

Tags: signal-processing, fft, octave, vibration

I must evaluate vibration of a car. For this trial I used accelerometer. Collected data are depended on the time.

I need to convert the data from time domain to frequency domain by FFT. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with coding and FTT very well, however I found and used the code below.

What is strange for me, that maximum high point has 0Hz. Please, see attached image.
Anyway, is there a way how to do a graph more obvious? For example, cut a series in x-axis and shows only data under 200Hz.

[image]

```
clc
A=xlsread('50_dirt_road.xlsx');
t=A(:,9);
s=A(:,8);
Ts = mean(diff(t));                                     % Sampling Interval
Fs = 1/Ts;                                              % Sampling Frequency
Fn = Fs/2;                                              % Nyquist Frequency
L = numel(t);                                           % Signal Length
sm = s - mean(s);                                       % Mean-Corrected Signal (Eliminates 0 Hz Offset)
FTs = fft(sm)/L;                                        % Fourier Transform
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;                     % Frequency Vector
Iv = 1:numel(Fv);                                       % Index Vector
[MaxV,idx] = max(abs(FTs(Iv))*2);                       % Maximum V & Index
Freq = Fv(idx);                                         % Frequency Of Maximum V
figure
plot(Fv, abs(FTs(Iv))*2)
grid
text(Freq, MaxV, sprintf('\\leftarrow %.4f G, %.0f Hz', MaxV, Freq), 'HorizontalAlignment','left')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Could you double check it, please? My variables are defined as follows:

- `s`: *measured "G" value*. In total 3395 measured values.
- `t`: *time*. Every single value was recorded after 0.001s, in total 3.395s.

Comment: I saw you put a link up earlier but I was too busy to check it out.  If you put it up I can pull the data down and see if I can get it to work, then I'll share the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum high point you are referring to is normal.  Without having frequency cut offs, the beginning, (nearest zero), of your fourier transform will always have the most spectral energy because it is resolving sampling rates tending towards zero which as you can imagine would have a ton of representation in the time series.  Obviously 0 hz is impossible, so you should choose a lower bound frequency that makes sense in the domain of car vibrations.  So I recommend a band pass filter, one that does forward and backward filtering (filt filt) to preserve the original time series and then running the result through this analysis.  I would start with a butterworth filter and experiment with othes if desired:

https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/butter.html

EDIT:

I was using t but the signal is in s.  Here is the whole thing:

```
clc
A=xlsread('50_dirt_road.xlsx');
t=A(:,9);
s=A(:,8);
Ts = mean(diff(t));                                     % Sampling Interval
Fs = 1/Ts;                                              % Sampling Frequency
Fn = Fs/2;                                              % Nyquist Frequency
L = numel(t);                                           % Signal Length

%1st order butterworth filter with a band pass of 1hz to 200hz in radians
%forward and reverse filtered
[b,a] = butter(1, [1/(L/2), 200/(L/2)]);
filtered_s = filtfilt(b,a,s);

sm = filtered_s - mean(filtered_s);                     % Mean-Corrected Signal (Eliminates 0 Hz Offset)
FTs = fft(sm)/L;                                        % Fourier Transform
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;                     % Frequency Vector
Iv = 1:numel(Fv);                                       % Index Vector
[MaxV,idx] = max(abs(FTs(Iv))*2);                       % Maximum V & Index
Freq = Fv(idx);                                         % Frequency Of Maximum V
figure
plot(Fv, abs(FTs(Iv))*2)
grid
text(Freq, MaxV, sprintf('\\leftarrow %.4f G, %.0f Hz', MaxV, Freq), 'HorizontalAlignment','left')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

LAST EDIT:

Okay, so I think I got you an intro in to the world of filtering when I think all you were looking to do is constrain the axis of your FFT.  Same arguments for the band pass filter above, 1hz and 200hz.  The above code should work but the following code is probably what you were looking for originally:

```
clc
A=xlsread('50_dirt_road.xlsx');
t=A(:,9);
s=A(:,8);
Ts = mean(diff(t));                                     % Sampling Interval
Fs = 1/Ts;                                              % Sampling Frequency
Fn = Fs/2;                                              % Nyquist Frequency
L = numel(t);                                           % Signal Length

sm = s - mean(s);                     % Mean-Corrected Signal (Eliminates 0 Hz Offset)
FTs = fft(sm)/L;                                        % Fourier Transform
Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;                     % Frequency Vector
freqMask = (Fv > 1) & (Fv < 200);
Fv = Fv(freqMask);
FTs = FTs(freqMask);
Iv = 1:numel(Fv);                                       % Index Vector
[MaxV,idx] = max(abs(FTs(Iv))*2);                       % Maximum V & Index
Freq = Fv(idx);                                         % Frequency Of Maximum V
figure
plot(Fv, abs(FTs(Iv))*2)
grid
text(Freq, MaxV, sprintf('\\leftarrow %.4f G, %.0f Hz', MaxV, Freq), 'HorizontalAlignment','left')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to it the same way, however Octave still tells me that syntax error related to the line with `[b,a] = butter(4, [Fn*2*pi), 200*2*pi]);` Is there something what missing to me? For example another package? At this moment, I use IO & Signal pkg. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a syntax error in there.  I removed it it is now: `[b,a] = butter(4, [Fn*2*pi, 200*2*pi]);`

Comment: I could recognize that there was an extra bracket. Unfortunately, the code is not working due to: _error: butter" W(1) must be less than W(2) & error: called from butter at line 111 column 7, test at line 12 column 7_ I've checked theory of Nyquist's Frequency, nevertheless, I don't have any glue what I do wrong.

Comment: Ok, sorry I made another mistake since I didn't run the data.  The Nyquist frequency is going to be 500hz if the sampling rate is .001 seconds, so that is above 200 hz.  I changed the explanation and changed the code to be 1 hz to 200hz, you should choose a lower cutoff frequency that makes sense for the car vibrations domain but for now I just chose 1hz to get you started.  Let me know if this works now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is still not working due to: _error: butter: all elements of Wc must be in the range [0,1], error: called from butter at line 166 column 5, latest at line 12 column 7._

Comment: It works, thank you very much for strong support!! The topic can be closed I think. How can I reward you?  To confirm, when I cut the series and keep the data let's say from 5Hz to 100Hz, the peak is 23Hz. Could you say, if this value can match with the real vibration in the car on normal road? Thank you in advance.

Comment: One comment from my side. _Fv = linspace(0, 1, fix(L/2)+1)*Fn;_ When I set for example 5 instead of 1, it means that graph will show us each 5 value? Also, _freqMask = (Fv > 1) & (Fv < 200);_ by this line, I am able now to cut the series. Can I consider, that frequencies that are not between 1-200 are noise?

Comment: No problem!  Just click the green check icon next to the answer to mark it as the correct answer.  I'm not a domain expert on car vibrations, but as long as the data is accurate yes it reflects the real vibration of the car on a normal road.  Keep the 1 in linear space, that's the range of frequency times the Nyquist frequency which messes up the math if replaced with 5.   5 is the limit argument.  The data outside of your range could be noise, but it up to you the expert to make that decision as to what frequencies are relevant for car vibrations.

Comment: Hi, I have one question. When the freqmask parameter set for example to Fv > 5 line is going to start on 5Hz in x-axis and the graph does not change the scale. Thus there there is a empty space between y-axis and starting point. I hope that the question is understandable. Can I somehow delete this space and set the beginning on 5Hz?

Comment: Try using this function after the plot function to change the x scale:  `xlim([5,200])` or whatever x limits you prefer.